# When exactly does $E(X|Y)$ mean? (X, Y are random variable)

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Am I correct that  $E(X|Y)$ is "expected value of $X$ conditional on *each* possible value of $Y$"?

I have this question because I wondered that $E(X|Y)$ means "expected value of $X$ conditional on all possible value of $Y$ *altogether*". However, then it sounds impossible to me that $E(X)$ can be unequal to $E(X|Y)$ even when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent of each other.

Comment: The answer to this question greatly depends on what level of probability are you doing. Are you studying an introduction to probability course (likely without measure theory), or advanced probability theory course (with measure theory)?

Comment: I am studying econometric methods in research (e.g. Difference-in-Difference).

Comment: Also take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable)

Comment: @drhab I did. But I am not sure whether I understood it correctly.

Comment: $E(X|Y)$ is the best predictor(minimum MSE) of $X$ when you have $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be random variables defined on the same probability space.

Then $E[X\mid Y]$ is the notation of a **random variable** with the following properties:

- $E[X\mid Y]$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$
- For every $A\in\sigma(Y)$ we have: $$\int_A X(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int_A E[X\mid Y](\omega)P(d\omega)$$

Often - if we are aiming to find $E[X\mid Y]$ - we can do that by calculating $f(y):=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$ and then draw the conclusion that $E[X\mid Y]=f(Y)$.

In the special case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent this results in a degenerated random variable: $\mathbb E[X\mid Y](\omega)=\mathbb EX$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Why is $f(Y)$ not equal to $E(X)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent of each other?

Comment: Because in that case $f(Y)$ is not degenerated. That means it is a **function** on $\Omega$ that can take several distinct values. This in contrast with $\mathbb EX$ which is a **constant** in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Actually also in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent it is formally not correct to identify $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ and $\mathbb EX$. This again because the first is a function on $\Omega$ and the second is a fixed real number. There however the fact that we are dealing with a **constant function** makes is possible to somehow "close our eyes" for that distinction.

Comment: A concrete example: $X$ is the height of child and $Y$ is the height of the mother. Obviously $X$ and $Y$ are dependent of each other. But how is it possible that $E(X) \neq E(X|Y)$, if $X$ is defined over the whole distribution of $Y$ (since both side of the equation seem to have the same interpretation)?

Comment: Again $\mathbb EX$ is a real number and $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is not a real number but is a random variable. This means that it makes no sense to compare them. Btw a random variable $X$ is not *defined over a distribution* of some other random variable $Y$ (as you state in your comment). This terminology makes no sense either.

Comment: What exactly is $EX$ in your answer? Is it expected value of X? Is $E(X|Y)$ also a random variable when $Y$ and $X$ are independent?

Comment: $\mathbb EX$ it indeed the expectation of random variable $X$. Further $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ is also a random variable when $Y$ and $X$ are independent. However in that special case it is special one: a random variable that satisfies $X(\omega)=\mathbb EX$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$. So it is a constant function. Formally *not* just a value in $\mathbb R$. However such constant functions are often 'blindly" identified with the (unique) value that it takes. Confusion lurks then and is ready to strike.